# Why Android Studio arm64 system images are slow?

Tags: android, performance, emulation, arm64

I got 32 gigs, gtx 1080 and i7 6700k intel processor and the arm64 emulations are slow and unusable, chrome crashes as soon as i type something, is there a solution for that

Comment: how is this a duplicate? never seen a problem like this on stackoverflow

Comment: Absolutely the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator

Comment: Absolutely not, im talking about arm64 images and also not slow in booting, the actual emulation is slow, but x86 images are fast and good

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7419753/436938